# How to convert decode/encode string to Base58?

Tags: solidity, remix, encoding

How to convert decode/encode string to Base58 on solidity?

Answer (score 2):

I know this repository contributes to the community: https://github.com/storyicon/base58-solidity

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe there's any built-in function for doing this, but here's a `toBase58` implementation: https://github.com/MrChico/verifyIPFS/blob/master/contracts/verifyIPFS.sol#L28.

Depending on your use case, it might be better to have Solidity deal with the raw bytes and convert to/from base58 outside of the contract (e.g. in JavaScript or whatever client language you're using).